# Problem installing OpenNI driver

Tags: ros, asus-xtion-pro-live, ubuntu, ubuntu-quantal, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to install drivers for my Primesense device (Asus Xtion Pro Live), but I'm getting a problem running the install.sh file. I'm running Groovy on Ubuntu 12.10.

After days of research, I realised there were two versions of the driver, one was from the openni.org website, and there was another version of it done by avin2 (https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect). I finally realised the avin2 one was for Kinect, and the openni.org one was for other Primesense devices (source here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openni-dev/Nw8J9WtRTTI, and https://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/wiki/Installation#Linux).

So, I downloaded the 32bit tarball from openni.org:

http://www.openni.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Sensor-Bin-Linux-x86-v5.1.2.1.tar.zip

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error running ./install.sh.
Here's what it looks like:

```
$ sudo ./install.sh 
Installing PrimeSense Sensor
****************************

creating config dir /usr/etc/primesense...OK
copying shared libraries...OK
copying executables...OK
registering module 'libXnDeviceSensorV2.so' with OpenNI..../install.sh: 105: ./install.sh: /usr/bin/niReg: not found
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I tried to sudo mkdir /usr/bin/niReg, but I'd still get an error running ./install.sh; it now becomes permission denied:

```
$ sudo ./install.sh 
Installing PrimeSense Sensor
****************************

creating config dir /usr/etc/primesense...OK
copying shared libraries...OK
copying executables...OK
registering module 'libXnDeviceSensorV2.so' with OpenNI..../install.sh: 106: ./install.sh: /usr/bin/niReg: Permission denied
```

Please help! Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71071/problem-installing-openni-driver/) by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 324 on 2013-08-04

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TomHsu1990](https://answers.ros.org/users/6019/tomhsu1990/) on 2013-08-16**:
I also faced the same problem. Does anyone have a solution?
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and Xtion. I had downloaded 32bit version of OpenNI2.2 and Sensorv5.1.2.1.

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2013-08-19**:
If I'm not mistaken, I think I read somewhere that the drivers (Sensor v5.1.2.1) only needs to be installed with the old version of OpenNI (v.1.5.4). The reason why it says the module is not found is because it only comes with OpenNI v1.5.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error occurred because I was trying to install the drivers with OpenNI 2.2 (which is not required). The drivers are only for the older version of OpenNI, v1.5.4.

---

Originally posted by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) with karma: 324 on 2013-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2013-12-22**:
My other question at http://answers.ros.org/question/70585/roslaunch-openni_launch-opennilaunch-no-devices-connected/ has help on how to get the drivers for v1.5 working.